# Why is initialization of enum class temporaries with arbitrary values allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across some code like the following in one the CppCon 2014 talks that confused the heck out of me.  The audience accepted it without comment, so I presume that it's legal:

```
enum class Foo { Bar };

Foo const v1 = Foo(5);
```

The question is: why does this compile?  I would expect compilation to fail and complain that we can't convert an int to a Foo.  The slightly modified line below fails with the expected error:

```
Foo const v1(5);
```

Comment: I think the Foo(5) is not a conversion (as your suggest in your post), but rather a C style cast ... and may be rewritten as  (Foo)5,  in C++ this would be reinterpret_cast<Foo>(5).

Comment: Right.  That's the bit that was tripping me up.  Just another dark corner of C++ that's best to be avoided. ;)

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN all casts are conversions.  An int can be converted to a Foo, but not implicitly converted.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I disagree.  No conversion happens with a cast.  The bits in memory are unchanged.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN see [expr.cast]/2 . It is called *explicit type conversion*.  A conversion need not change any bits.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - agreed - a conversion need not change any bits.   So, you are telling me that Foo(5) is not a c-style cast.  Guess I'll go review what makes this a conversion and not a cast.  Thanks.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN It is the same effect as  C-style cast. What I'm saying is that it is also a conversion. All casts are conversions. Some conversions are casts.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I have found lots of confusing and contradicting items, most stating something along the lines of "... the semantically most meaningful distinction of the two terms [conversion, casting]. But C++ doesn’t follow this distinction."   Don't know what the standards say, but, probably, I no longer care and henceforth will try to stay out of such issues.  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scoped enumeration types have an implicit underlying type of `int`, assuming no other underlying type is specified. All possible values of type `int` can be represented.

7.2p5:

> [...] For a scoped enumeration type, the underlying type is `int` if it is not explicitly specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type
>   is said to be *fixed*. [...]

7.2p8:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. [...]

And any integral value that can be represented by the enumeration can be explicitly converted to that enumeration type, as @Columbo had pointed out in his now-deleted answer:

5.2.9p10:

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). [...]

Since there is some confusion in the comments about what that means:

> ```
> enum class Foo { Bar };
>
> Foo const v1 = Foo(5);
> ```

is well-defined. Not undefined, not unspecified, not even implementation-defined. The parts of the standard I quote explain that:

1. The underlying type of `Foo` is `int`, and that the underlying type is fixed.
2. The values of `Foo` are the values of `int`.
3. Since `5` is in the range of the enumeration values, the value is unchanged by the conversion.

Comment: So you're saying the fact that `Foo f(5);` compiles on neither clang nor gcc is a bug?

Comment: @Barry No, I'm not. The standard allows for an explicit conversion, but `Foo f(5);` attempts to perform an implicit conversion.

Comment: How is that implicit?

Comment: @Barry It's the same way `void *p = 1;` doesn't compile, `void *p(1);` doesn't compile, but `void *p = reinterpret_cast<void *>(1);` or `void *p = (void *) 1;` does compile. Yes, it's a context where explicit constructors are accepted, but that doesn't make it an explicit conversion.

Comment: Considering opaque declarations, wouldn't it also be valid to say that in addition to 5.2.9/10 allowing this with "unspecified result", it is legal from the compiler's point of view since it has no way of knowing at that point whether the enumeration does or indeed does not have that enumeration value?

Comment: A practical use case of this (enums with values outside of their enumerated list) is bitfields with overloaded `operator|` etc.

Comment: @Damon No, there is no unspecified result here. The result is specified, because it is within the range of the enumeration values. If the value were outside of that range, then the compiler would still pretty much be required to accept it, but it could fail badly at run-time (the "unspecified" has since become "undefined"), and I wouldn't call it "legal".

Comment: @hvd What is an "explicit conversion" then? In expr.static.cast, it's sort of defined in terms of `T t(e)`, but in this case the `static_cast` is valid but that construction is not.

Comment: I think the bit I was missing is that Foo(5) is a function-style cast and not a constructor invocation.  In any case, it seems clear that this example is seriously bad form since (if I understand correctly), `Foo const v1 = Foo(5)` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Barry A conversion that has some syntax to make the operation explicit. In other words, a cast. expr.static.cast states that if `T t(e);` is valid, then `static_cast` does the same thing, but it is followed by some other conversions that can also be performed by `static_cast`.

Comment: Ok.  Let me try again. :)  If the enumeration is _fixed_ (i.e. it was declared with "enum class") then the legal values of the enumeration are the same as the underlying type.  If the numeration is _not_ fixed (i.e. it was declared with "enum") then the legal values are essentially everything in the range [e-min, e-max].  So if I tweaked my example above a removed the "class" keyword, then the assignment would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterRuderman No, legal values would be in b-min and b-max, respectively. Otherwise your explanation is correct. I forgot about the exact definition of a fixed underlying type >:(

Comment: @PeterRuderman That's mostly right, except that e-min and e-max are rounded up so that they exactly map to a whole number of bits.