# Why am I allowed to use an incomplete enum class?

Tags: c++

Why does the code below compile without any errors?

```
enum class Enumeration;
void func()
{
    auto enumeration = static_cast<Enumeration>(2);
    auto value = static_cast<int>(enumeration);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is initialization of enum class temporaries with arbitrary values allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852922/why-is-initialization-of-enum-class-temporaries-with-arbitrary-values-allowed)

Comment: Is there some reason it shouldn't?

Comment: You have declated a: _"Opaque enum declaration: defines the enumeration type but not its enumerators: after this declaration, the type is a complete type and its size is known."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: the standard allows this. it may not be exceedingly useful. see also here what it was originally intended for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18338930/1132334

Comment: So, it's _not_ incomplete; it just does not have any enumerators.

Comment: Examples when such enums are useful would be an excellent answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten You should turn that into an answer. You have a lot of comments that are good answers.

Comment: It's because of [`[dcl.enum]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#3), but I don't know what the motivation is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compiles because the compiler knows at compile time the size of `Enumeration` (which happens to be empty).

You see it  explicitly using the following syntax:

```
 enum class Enumeration : short;
```

The compiler knows everything there is to know about the `Enumeration`.
`Enumeration` is a **opaque-enum-declaration** which means also that the type is `complete` i.e. you can use `sizeof`on it. If needed you can specify  the list of enumerators  in a later redeclaration (unless the redeclaration comes with a different underlying type, obviously).

Note that since you are using `enum class` usage of `static_cast` is mandatory.

- Strongly typed enum does not allow implicit conversion to `int` but you can safely use `static_cast` on them to retrieve their integral value.

They are still `enum` afterall.

[Quoting cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

> There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped
>   enumerator to integral types, although static_cast may be used to
>   obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

More on this topic here: [How to automatically convert strongly typed enum into int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357240/how-to-automatically-convert-strongly-typed-enum-into-int)